Getting Error from Redis reconnect: "MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20)
I'm trying to create Redis rate limiter with express-rate-limiter ioradis
and rate-limit-redis libraries
After I started the application I got the below error message
MaxRetriesPerRequestError: Reached the max retries per request limit (which is 20). Refer to "maxRetriesPerRequest" option for details.
Please let me know if encounter the same !!

Share code please
